# Issue while defining jQuery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Trying to define a couple of functions like so:

```
user = (function() {
    var friends_list = (function() {
        $.get('/ajax/user/friends_list', function(data) {
                  ......
```

So I can later on call them when need it like so `user.friends_list()` but for now, the only thing I get is this following error:

```
TypeError: Object function () {
 var friends_list = (function() {
 $.get(....
```

I just don't know where else to look, any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show sample code snippet of function just giving the starting wont help. what are you retruning at the end of function?

Comment: I actually don't return anything, just work out the dom according to the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a user object and not function

```
var user = {
  friends_list : function(){
     $.get('/ajax/user/friends_list', function(data) {
              ......
  }
 }
```

and call it like.. `user.friends_list()`

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/VHwxz/)

Comment: this did it... for some reason, Arun's suggestion by using `friends_list = function` doesn't work...

Comment: He uses `=`, where `:` should be used. See my answer if you want to get some encapsulation of private variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create user as an object, in your case the `friends_list` is a closure method, it will be availble outside the function

```
user = {
    friends_list : function(){
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be `friend_list: function`, not `=`. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using a closure here, so `friend_list` is invisible on the outside of `user`.

If you want to use closures, to hide some variables, to best way to export `friend_list` would be:

```
(function(){
    var somePrivateVariable;

    window.user = {};
    window.user.friend_list = function() {
        // make use of somePrivateVariable...
    };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
user = function() {
this.friends_list = function() {
    $.get('/ajax/user/friends_list', function(data) {
              ......
     });
 };
 return this;
};
```

Above should also work. 
reference http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Agz/)

Here is the code:

```
var global = {};

global.sayHello = function (x){
    //do your code here
      console.log('Hello ' + x );  
};
global.sayHello('Kevin');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user = new function(){
   var private_variable;
   function private_method(){}

   this.global_variable = '';
   this.global_method = function(){};
}
```